# Adding a row to a data table in a csv using r

Tags: dataframe, csv, write.table

Trying to use the below code to add a row at the end of a data table in a csv. The code adds the row beside the current last row instead of below it?
Has anyone ever had that problem?

```
v1="chicago"
v2="USA"
v3="North America"

city_info <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)

write.table(city_info, file = "/Users/v10.csv",
            sep = ",", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmurA.png)

[What I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQaeR.png)

[what I'm getting when sep = ";"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtK6D.png)

Comment: Could you provide the output you're getting?

Comment: Just did. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sep = ";"`? Same output?

Comment: Yes, there's a similar problem when sep = ";". I added the picture. Thanks

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. When I set up an exactly identical .csv file as yours and execute your code, then it works for me.